# How to write xpath to combine a text from a tooltip in a case like this?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, tooltip

In this element, text is not together in this line:

```
<div class="tooltip-inner"> Downtime <br _ngcontent-shw-c48=""> 1.1h </div>
```

But in console using **xpath**, I want to combine and print the text in single line
like this: "**Downtime 1.1h**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `normalize-space` with the following XPath :

In your browser console :

```
$x("normalize-space(//div[@class='tooltip-inner'])")
```

Output : `Downtime 1.1h`

Comment: It didn't work, but I marked it as solved as of now.